# Parsing an xml with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm really new to XML parsing and need some help. Suppose an xml such as this one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
  <node:config xmlns:node="uri:example.com/somepath/node/10.0" xmlns:this="uri:example.com/somepath/this/10.0" xmlns:that="uri:example.com/somepath/node/10.0" xmlns:thus="uri:example.com/somepath/thus/10.0" xmlns:an="uri:example.com/somepath/an/10.0">
    <this:is.a.test>on</this:is.a.test>
    <that:was.some.thing>off</that:was.some.thing>
    <thus:can name="species" value="value1 value2">
      <an:idea.for.something>on</an:idea.for.something>
      <an:idea.for.something.else>on</an:idea.for.something.else>
    </thus:can>
    <thus:can name="monkey" value="value3 value4">
      <an:idea.for.something>off</an:idea.for.something>
      <an:idea.for.something.else>off</an:idea.for.something.else>
    </thus:can>
  </node:config>
</top>
```

How would I go about printing everything inside of the "thus" namespace when name=species and value=value1 for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To select the whole block `thus:can`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N thus="uri:example.com/somepath/thus/10.0" -t -c '//thus:can'
```

Next refine to only those having attrib `name="species"`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N thus="uri:example.com/somepath/thus/10.0" -t -c '//thus:can[@name="species"]'
```

Or those which somewhere have the string "value1" in the attrib `value`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N thus="uri:example.com/somepath/thus/10.0" -t -c '//thus:can[contains(@value,"value1")]'
```

And the 2 restrictions combined:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N thus="uri:example.com/somepath/thus/10.0" -t -c '//thus:can[@name="species" and contains(@value,"value1")]'
```

Beware that when your `value=..` attribute should have well defined internal delimiters, to avoid matching an unwanted substring:

```
... value="apple grapefruit" ...
... value="monkey ape chimp" ...
```

and then searching for `contains(@value,"ape")` this will match both values (because gr*ape*fruit contains *ape*).  Add some delimeters between, and also at start plus end, e.g. a colon:

```
.... value=":apple:grapefruit:"
```

and searching with:

```
contains(@value,":ape:")
```

does not match that value, but only the real `x:ape:y`.

Comment: Good answer. A couple comments though: In your third example, the syntax for contains is incorrect (`contains(@value="value1"`). It looks correct in the fourth example though. Also, for your last example, if the OP can't change the XML input, concat can be used to make sure correct values are matched: `contains(concat(" ",@value," ")," ape ")`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - I fixed the 3rd example.  And concat() is indeed a good solution for the "full token" matching.